McNemar test as z test or chi squared test
I am a TA in an intro statistics class. We are introducing students to the McNemar test to compare two proportions on a dependent sample. I noticed the textbook we are using frames the McNemar test as z statistic following a z distribution:
$$
z = \frac{b-c}{\sqrt{b+c}}
$$
whereas other sources such as Wikipedia frame the test statistic as following the chi-squared distribution
$$
\chi_1^2 = \frac{(b-c)^2}{b+c}
$$
I am aware from mathematical statistics that a z statistic squared follows a chi-squared distribution with degree of freedom 1.
Does anyone know why one may prefer one framing as a z test or the other? I think the two statistics will produce the same inferences. I suspect students may be confused if they decide to do their own reading on the subject.
Framing the test as a z test does allow the calculation of the standard error which is not relevant for the chi-squared framing.

Strictly the test statistic is discrete (in either form) since it's based on counts; indeed under the assumptions (conditional on $n=b+c$), $b-c$ is a scaled and shifted binomial.

The normal and chi-squared are approximations to the null distribution function (i.e. the cdf) of those discrete statistics. For a two-sided alternative, they yield equivalent tests (as long as they either both  ignore or both include a continuity correction). So usually there's not a particular reason to prefer one over the other ― aside, perhaps, that interpreting a "z" score is likely to be slightly more familiar.

Does anyone know why one may prefer one framing as a z test or the other?

If you want a one tailed test you don't want to square it.
If you want to combine several such statistics for an omnibus test over multiple independent groups (where the effects might not all be the same), then you'd presumably want the squared form (so you can add them without cancelling potentially opposed effects).
If you wanted an exact test it would be simpler if you leave it as "b" (binomial test) or "b-c" (sign test, which in turn is based on the binomial when doing it as an exact test).

I would strongly NOT recommend to use McNemar test, since commonly it is impossible to reasonably interpret its results. An example in R:
> f=c(rep(1,1000),rep(0,4000))
> g1=c(rep(1,1010),rep(0,3990))
> g2=c(rep(0,3990),rep(1,1010))
> mcnemar.test(f,g1)
    McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
data:  f and g1
McNemar's chi-squared = 8.1, df = 1, p-value = 0.004427
> mcnemar.test(f,g2)
    McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
data:  f and g2
McNemar's chi-squared = 0.040299, df = 1, p-value = 0.8409

We get p = 0.0044 for mcnemar.test(f,g1) and p = 0.84 for mcnemar.test(f,g2), though the vectors g1 and g2 consist of the same numbers of ones and zeros. How can this be reasonably interpreted?
I would strongly recommend to use conditional logistic regression instead.
The main problem with McNemar test is that it restricts the numbers of unchanged and changed cells to the observed ones. In other words, it assumes that the numbers $a+d$ and $b+c$ were fixed in the experiment, which is always not the case. This drastically influences the results which are usually garbage.
